# Skipping empty lists when mapping two existing objects

Tags: c#, automapper

Working on supporting legacy code, basically what I need is to merge 2 objects together. One is from UI, and everything is null or empty collection (and I dont want that), second is the same, fresh from database.I want to overwrite non-null,not-empty values from source to destination, leaving everything else intact. I do :

```
Mapper.Map(model, result);
```

I resolve unwanted properties by using:

```
    cfg.CreateMap<ClientItem, ClientItem>().ForAllMembers(a =>
            {
                a.ResolveUsing<IgnoreNullSourceValues, object>(a.DestinationMember.Name);
            });
```

My custom class for this is:

```
class IgnoreNullSourceValues : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, object>
    {
        public object Resolve(object source, object destination, object sourceMember, object destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            if (sourceMember is IList)
            {
                var a = (IList)sourceMember;
                if (a.Count == 0)
                    return destinationMember;
            }

            if (sourceMember is DateTime)
            {
                var a = (DateTime)sourceMember;
                if (a == DateTime.MinValue)
                    return destinationMember;
            }
            return sourceMember ?? destinationMember;
        }
    }
```

It works with everything, but when I debug, I see for example empty List on sourceMember, good list in destinationMember, I see that it returns destinationMember, yet in setter I see that it then binds empty list. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Issue

It appears that AutoMapper calls `Clear()` on destination lists after calling `Resolve()` but before setting the new value. This means that the value of `destinationMember` will actually change before the setter is called. You can (roughly) confirm this by changing types of `IList` to `ObservableCollection` and listening for changes on the destination collection. For example:

```cs
var clearedCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
clearedCollection.CollectionChanged += ClearedCollection_CollectionChanged;

var model = new ClientItem() { Test = new ObservableCollection<int>() };
var result = new ClientItem() { Test = clearedCollection };

Mapper.Map(model, result);
```

```cs
class ClientItem
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> test;
    public ObservableCollection<int> Test
    {
        get
        {
            return test;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Set");
            test = value;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
private static void ClearedCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, 
System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Action);
}
```

```cs
public object Resolve(object source, object destination, object sourceMember, object destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Resolve");
    ...
}
```

will output

```
Set
Set
Resolve
Reset
Add
Add
Add
Set
```

The first two `set`s are for the initialization of the ClientItems. After `Resolve` is called, the destination is `Reset` so that items from the list returned from `Resolve` can be `Add`ed. Since the list returned from `Resolve` is the same one that was `Reset`, there is nothing to add anymore. The last `set` is where this blank list is being added back to the ClientItem (which is what you're seeing when you debug).

### Solution

In order to ensure that the collection remains intact during the operation, you could copy the returned value:

```cs
class IgnoreNullSourceValues : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, 
object>
{
    public object Resolve(object source, object destination, object sourceMember, object destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destinationMember is IList)
        {
            var a = (IList)sourceMember;
            if (a == null || a.Count == 0)
                return CopyIList(destinationMember as IList);
        }

        if (sourceMember is DateTime)
        {
            var a = (DateTime)sourceMember;
            if (a == DateTime.MinValue)
                return destinationMember;
        }
        return sourceMember ?? destinationMember;
    }

    private static IList CopyIList(IList list)
    {
        var ret = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(list.GetType());
        foreach (var item in list)
            ret.Add(item);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Note in the above code I switched the first if statement to take `destinationMember` instead of `sourceMember`. This was because the if statement would evaluate to false if `sourceMember` was null, even if it was an `IList`. That was fine in the code you had, but here the copy method needs to be called in this case.

This workaround seems to indicate that this might not be the intended behaviour. I might file an issue in the AutoMapper issue tracker and see what becomes of it.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html). AutoMapper.Collection might help.